# CoffeeScript, What is the difference between => and ->

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am new to CoffeeScript. I have run into this today.

```
example -> 
 a ->
```

and

```
example ->
 b =>
```

What this the different between a thin arrow vs a fat arrow?

Could someone please explain the difference and when they should be used.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not reading the documentation. 

Comment: @ rlemon I do not feel it is off topic, I was reading the documentation and did not understand.

Comment: @Tyler ==> right here: http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fat arrow `=>` defines a function bound to the current value of `this`.

This is handy especially for callbacks.

Notice the generated differences

Coffee script:

```
foo = () -> this.x + this.x;
bar = () => this.x + this.x;
```

JavaScript

```
var bar, foo,
  _this = this;

foo = function() {
  return this.x + this.x;
};

bar = function() {
  return _this.x + _this.x;
};
```

Comment: what is the difference between _this and this?

Comment: @Tyler `_this` is just a variable name. `this` is a language keyword (in JS, think of @ in CS)

Comment: ok I know what this means I was just unclear on _this

Comment: @Tyler - javascript binds events and functions to the caller - so `this` might not be your object.